# Problema al llamar a un input en función para control de existencias con JQUERY

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysqli

**Script donde envio la información y la muestro**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btcar').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var car = $(this).attr("id");
        var stock = $('#stock'+car).val();
        var stock1 = parseInt(stock);  

        var prue = $('#prue').attr("value");  
        var prue1 = parseInt(prue);

        var cant = $('#canti'+prue1).val();
        var cant1 = parseInt(cant);

        alert(cant1);

        if(stock1 > 1 && stock1 != cant1 ){
          $.ajax({

              url:'carrito.php',
              method: 'POST',
              data:{car:car, prue:prue},
              type:JSON,
              success:function(deta){
                $('#carrito').html(deta);
              }
          });
        } else{
          alert ("Exedio el limite");
        }
    }); 

    $('#carrito').load("carrito.php");

  });
</script>
```

**Datos que quiero recibir al enviar**

Resulta que este input al yo dar click btcar me va generando pedidos. El punto es que esos pedido tiene un stock , y ese stock pienso sacarlo de la cantidad de veces que yo de click al btcar que se me irá almacenando en el input de class canti obviamente si el pedido es diferente me lo genera en otra input aparte el punto es que yo logro tomar el valor del primer input y logro que no siga sumando cuando este es alcanza el stock máximo pero los otros que se me van generando automáticamente dependiendo el pedido que yo seleccione no me lo reconoce me toma siempre el valor del primero.

```
<input type="hidden" id="prue" value="<?php echo $i ?>">
<input type="text" class="canti" id="canti<?php echo $i ?>" name="cantidad" min="1" maxlength="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock']; ?>" value="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['cantidad']; ?>" style="text-alaing: center;">
```

Comment: explica un poco mejor que quieres hacer exactamente.

Comment: Amigo en conclusión a ver si me explico mejor, no logro hacer que la cantidad seleccionada no me supere el stock , es un carrito donde van seleccionando y al dar click se va agregando y estos van apareciendo en una tabla , lo que no logro hacer es que la cantidad no me supere al stock , solo me respeta la condición del primer articulo que seleccione , del resto puedo exederme

Comment: Por favor ordena y modifica tu pregunta, no logro comprender que es exactamente lo que necesitas, cual es el error o cual es tu objetivo??

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema es en la validación estas colocando que sea diferente cuando debería ser si el Stock es mayor o igual a Cantidad:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btcar').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var car = $(this).attr("id");
        var stock = $('#stock'+car).val();
        var stock1 = parseInt(stock);
        var prue = $('#prue').attr("value");  
        var prue1 = parseInt(prue);
        var cant = $('#canti'+prue1).val();
        var cant1 = parseInt(cant);
        alert(cant1);
        if(stock1 > 1 && stock1 >= cant1 ){
          $.ajax({
              url:'carrito.php',
              method: 'POST',
              data:{car:car, prue:prue},
              type:JSON,
              success:function(deta){
                $('#carrito').html(deta);
              }
          });
        } else{
          alert ("Exedio el limite");
        }
    }); 
    $('#carrito').load("carrito.php");
  });
</script>
```